# Problem with keyEvent in Java FXML and Scene Builder

Tags: java, fxml, keyevent

I want to make something happen on screen when i press som buttons. I know how events work but never worked with key Events in java. If someone can tell me why this code dont work, it would be great. :)

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private Rectangle Player;
@FXML
private Label lb;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}

@FXML
private void moveEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        lb.setText("RIGHT");
        System.out.println("Right");

    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {

    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {

    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {

    }
}
```

}